# How to change cell formatting dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid

I hava implemented a datagrid using dojo which get updated every 5 seconds. I use following code to update the datagrid.

```
jsonStore.fetch({
         query: {id:'*'},
         onComplete: function(items, result){
         dojo.forEach(items, function(item){
             jsonStore.setValue(item, "time" , data.update[0].netchange);
.....
```

'data' is the new data i need to set to the grid which is an json object as follows

```
var data = {"update":[{...}]}
```

what I need to do if the netchage is negative i need set cell color to red. if netchange is positive it should be green. So I need a way to change cell formatting dynamically. can some one please tell me how to this. thanks in advance

```
grid4 = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
            query : {
                Title : '*'
            },
            id : "grid",
            jsId : "grid",
            clientSort : true,
            rowSelector : '0px',
            structure : layout4
        }, document.createElement('div'));
        grid4.setStore(jsonStore);
        dojo.byId("gridContainer4").appendChild(grid4.domNode);

var layout4 = [ {
            field : 'time',
            name : 'time',
            width : '40px',
            formatter: geticon()
        }, {
            field : 'netchange',
            name : 'netchange',
            width : '30px'
        } ];
```

Comment: The answer will be in your DataGrid configuration. You should post that.

Comment: Your layout4 is wrong by the way. Unless geticon() returns a function, then you aren't passing a handler, you are calling the function directly from within the formatter. Remove the () from geticon and it should be okay.

Comment: I have tried answering it here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076701/dojo-data-grid-row-color-change-when-a-cell-gets-edited/17257449#17257449

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before I answer the question, just a trivial misnomer when you say, "change the cell formatting dynamically".

You aren't changing the cell `formatter`, you are changing how the *cell is styled*.

Every time a value is loaded into a cell, the formatter is called. Additionally, the onStyleROw function is called for the row that the cell is within.

This means that you have **two** options for changing the color of the cell. You can do it on a cell wide basis, or you can have your formatter do something simple like wrapping the value with a `<span>` that has a different style color. I'll show you both.

Here is the first solution without changing any of your existing grid code and it will change the entire row using onStyleRow.

## Solution 1 using onStyleRow

### Step 1.  (Connect the onStyleRow)

> dojo.connect( grid4, "onStyleRow", styleRowGridPayment  );

### Step 2. (Create you `styleRowGridPayment` method.)

```
var styleGridPayment = function(inRow) {
        if( null !== grid4.getItem( inRow.index ) ) {
            item = grid4.getItem( inRow.index );
            if( item.netchange < 0 ) {
                inRow.customStyles += "color:red;";
            } else {
                inRow.customStyles += "color:green;";
            }
         }
    }
```

That should do it for using onStyleRow.

## Solution 2, using the formatter

In your field declaration, you would have

```
{
    field : 'netchange',
    name : 'netchange',
    width : '30px'
    formatter: formatNetchange
}
```

Notice that I have added the formatNetchange as the formatter.

Then you just create your formatter.

```
formatNetchange = function(value){
     if(value < 0){
        color = "red";
     } else {
        color = "green";
     }
     return "<span style='color:" + color "'>" + value "</span>";
}
```