# Changing enhancedGrid row color background

Tags: datagrid, dojo, row, background-color, styling

I'm trying to change the background color for a row in a enhancedGrid. This is driving me crazy, thank you in advance for your time.

First, I select the row with onRowClick event.

```
      function onRowClickHandler(evt) {
             selectedRow = evt.rowIndex;
             selectedCode = dijit.byId("myGrid").getItem(evt.rowIndex).code;
      }
```

I need that the background color changes only when acertain button is clicked.

```
        dijit.byId("myGrid").getRowNode(selectedRow).style+="backgroungColor:red;");
```

or

```
        dijit.byId("myGrid").getRowNode(selectedRow).customStyle+="backgroungColor:red;");
```

This doesn't work.

I also tried with onStyleRow but it doesn't work.

I've tried with

```
    dojo.style(dijit.byId("myGrid").getRowNode(selectedRow), "backgroundColor", "#454545" )
```

But the style does not remain fixed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221058/how-to-change-cell-formatting-dynamically)

Though I think if you override onStyleRow instead of using dojo.connect you should have this at the bottom of your custom function:

```
dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid.prototype.onStyleRow.apply(this, arguments);
```